# Ao usar a Boleto.NET é preciso montar o arquivo remessa manualmente?

Tags: .net, winforms, boleto, c#

Em um sistema financeiro já construído por outro desenvolvedor a biblioteca Boleto.NET foi usada para geração de boletos do Itaú. Eu precisaria adicionar suporte a geração de boletos do Santander, mas não consigo descobrir de jeito nenhum como usar a biblioteca.

O código do outro desenvolvedor é extremamente confuso. É uma bagunça absurda, eu não consigo descobrir o que ele está fazendo.

Apesar de usar a biblioteca ele gera os arquivos remessa na mão, usando um código que parece extremamente dependente do banco.

Já nos exemplos da biblioteca no GitHub, o arquivo remessa é gerado pela propria API dela.

Minha pergunta aqui é a seguinte: ao usar a Boleto.NET eu posso usar os métodos dela para gerar o arquivo remessa, ou é necessário esse trabalho manual mesmo?

Comment: Realmente é confuso, mas eu já implementei arquivo de remessa pela propria API. Tive que fazer algumas modificações, mas no fim deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que desenvolvedor anterior não usou a ferramenta corretamente. Atualmente eu uso a Boleto2Net que é um refatoring da BoletoNet https://github.com/BoletoNet/boleto2net, aqui está uma rápida explicação do que muda entre os projetos: https://github.com/BoletoNet/boleto2net/issues/1.

Entendi como usar o componente com uma reposta de um dos contribuidores em uma issue, ele postou um trecho de código que está presente nos testes unitários que praticamente sana todas as dúvidas de preencher os atributos (https://github.com/BoletoNet/boleto2net/issues/31#issuecomment-328541440).

Depois do boleto preenchido (independente se Santander, Itau, etc)... basta seguir o exemplo que postei nesta outra issue: https://github.com/BoletoNet/boleto2net/issues/46.

O código que uso para gerar boleto no meu software é este

```
Boletos boletos = null;

boletos = new Boletos();

//Cabeçalho
boletos.Banco = Banco.Instancia(this.Conta.Banco.Numero);
boletos.Banco.Cedente = new Cedente
{
    CPFCNPJ = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Cnpj,
    Nome = this.Conta.Titular,
    Observacoes = string.Empty,
    ContaBancaria = new ContaBancaria
    {
        Agencia = this.Conta.Agencia,
        DigitoAgencia = this.Conta.AgenciaDigito,
        OperacaoConta = string.Empty,
        Conta = this.Conta.Numero,
        DigitoConta = this.Conta.NumeroDigito,
        CarteiraPadrao = this.Conta.CarteiraBoleto,
        VariacaoCarteiraPadrao = this.Conta.VariacaoCarteira,
        TipoCarteiraPadrao = TipoCarteira.CarteiraCobrancaSimples,
        TipoFormaCadastramento = TipoFormaCadastramento.ComRegistro,
        TipoImpressaoBoleto = this.Conta.Emissor == EmissaoBoleto.Banco ? TipoImpressaoBoleto.Banco : TipoImpressaoBoleto.Empresa,
        TipoDocumento = TipoDocumento.Tradicional
    },
    Codigo = this.Conta.CedenteNumero,
    CodigoDV = this.Conta.CedenteDigito.ToString(),
    CodigoTransmissao = string.Empty,
    Endereco = new Boleto2Net.Endereco
    {
        LogradouroEndereco = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Logradouro,
        LogradouroNumero = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Numero,
        LogradouroComplemento = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Complemento,
        Bairro = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Bairro,
        Cidade = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Cidade.Nome,
        UF = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Cidade.Uf.ToString(),
        CEP = Globals.DadosEmpresa.Endereco.Cep
    }
};
boletos.Banco.FormataCedente();

//Títulos
foreach (var cr in crs)
{
    var boleto = new Boleto(boletos.Banco);
    boleto.Sacado = new Sacado
    {
        CPFCNPJ = cr.Cliente.Cnpj,
        Nome = cr.Cliente.Razao,
        Observacoes = string.Empty,
        Endereco = new Boleto2Net.Endereco
        {
            LogradouroEndereco = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Logradouro,
            LogradouroNumero = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Numero,
            LogradouroComplemento = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Complemento,
            Bairro = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Bairro,
            Cidade = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Cidade.Nome,
            UF = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Cidade.Uf.ToString(),
            CEP = cr.Cliente.Endereco.Cep
        }
    };

    boleto.CodigoOcorrencia = "01"; //Registrar remessa
    boleto.DescricaoOcorrencia = "Remessa Registrar";

    boleto.NumeroDocumento = cr.Codigo.ToString();
    boleto.NumeroControleParticipante = cr.Codigo.ToString();
    boleto.NossoNumero = cr.Codigo.ToString();

    boleto.DataEmissao = cr.Lancamento;
    boleto.DataVencimento = cr.Vencimento;
    boleto.ValorTitulo = cr.ValorAberto;
    boleto.Aceite = "N";
    boleto.EspecieDocumento = TipoEspecieDocumento.DM;

    //boleto.DataDesconto = DateTime.Today;
    //boleto.ValorDesconto = 0;
    if (this.Conta.PercentualMulta > 0)
    {
        boleto.DataMulta = cr.Vencimento.AddDays(1);
        boleto.PercentualMulta = this.Conta.PercentualMulta;
        boleto.ValorMulta = boleto.ValorTitulo * boleto.PercentualMulta / 100;

        boleto.MensagemInstrucoesCaixa = $"Cobrar Multa de {boleto.ValorMulta.FormatoMoeda()} após o vencimento.";
    }

    if (this.Conta.PercentualMora > 0)
    {
        boleto.DataJuros = cr.Vencimento.AddDays(1);
        boleto.PercentualJurosDia = (this.Conta.PercentualMora / 30);
        boleto.ValorJurosDia = boleto.ValorTitulo * boleto.PercentualJurosDia / 100;

        string instrucao = $"Cobrar juros de {boleto.PercentualJurosDia.FormatoPorcentagem()} por dia de atraso";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(boleto.MensagemInstrucoesCaixa))
            boleto.MensagemInstrucoesCaixa = instrucao;
        else
            boleto.MensagemInstrucoesCaixa += Environment.NewLine + instrucao;
    }

    /*
    boleto.CodigoInstrucao1 = string.Empty;
    boleto.ComplementoInstrucao1 = string.Empty;

    boleto.CodigoInstrucao2 = string.Empty;
    boleto.ComplementoInstrucao2 = string.Empty;

    boleto.CodigoInstrucao3 = string.Empty;
    boleto.ComplementoInstrucao3 = string.Empty;                
    */

    boleto.CodigoProtesto = this.Conta.DiasProtesto == 0 ? TipoCodigoProtesto.NaoProtestar : TipoCodigoProtesto.ProtestarDiasuteis;
    boleto.DiasProtesto = this.Conta.DiasProtesto;

    boleto.CodigoBaixaDevolucao = TipoCodigoBaixaDevolucao.NaoBaixarNaoDevolver;
    boleto.DiasBaixaDevolucao = 0;

    boleto.ValidarDados();
    boletos.Add(boleto);
}
#endregion Daddos do título

//Gerar Remessa
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var remessa = new ArquivoRemessa(boletos.Banco, this.Conta.LayoutRemessa == LayoutRemessa.Cnab240 ? TipoArquivo.CNAB240 : TipoArquivo.CNAB400, this.Conta.SequencialRemessa);
remessa.GerarArquivoRemessa(boletos, stream);


//Gerar boletos - aqui eu gravo os arquivos um a um porque mando via e-mail.
 foreach (var boleto in boletos)
{
    var boletoBancario = new BoletoBancario() { Boleto = boleto };
    var pdf = boletoBancario.MontaBytesPDF(false);
    var pathPDF = GArquivos.CombinarDiretorio(PathRemessa, $"{boleto.NumeroControleParticipante}.pdf");
    File.WriteAllBytes(pathPDF, pdf);
}
```